# Custom credit card module | Direct integration | PikPay Payment Gatway

Tags: payment, payment-gateway

Here is the link of internet payment gateway in my country:

https://ipg.pikpay.ba/

There are two ways to integrate this payment gateway.

1. **Form integration**
   https://ipg.pikpay.ba/en/documentation/form

and

2. **Direct integration** (which I would like to use)
   https://ipg.pikpay.ba/en/documentation/direct

Has anybody ever tried to implement custom payment in Magento. Basically this is whole documentation I have. Any suggestion how do this. Any tutorial you can point me to.

Comment: Take a look at http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/05/01/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based/

Comment: sure, will take a look. Will inform back what I did, and how it went.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any issues.